# javascript isn't running in my JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm trying to make it so that i can validate the input when the user submits the form, but for some reason the javascript in my jsp isn't being implemented. any one have any idea?

code is posted below

Javascript:

```
function validate()
{
    if(document.updateForm.fName.value == "")
    {
        alert(" Please provide your first name." );
        document.updateForm.fName.focus();
        return false;
    }
    {
        if(document.updateForm.lName.value == "")
        {
            alert(" Please provide your last name." );
            document.updateForm.lName.focus();
            return false;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<h1>People Library - Update a Person</h1>

<form name="updateForm" action="updatePerson" onSubmit="return validate()" method=get>
<Label>
Person ID: 
</Label>
<input type=text name=personID value="<%= person.getPersonID() %>"/>
<br />

<Label>
First Name
</Label>
<input type=text name=fName value="" />
<Label>
<br />
Last Name
</Label>
<input type=text name =lName value="" />
<Label>
<br />
age
</Label>
<input type=text name=age value="<%= person.getAge() %>" />
<br />

<input type=submit name=submit value="Update the Person" />


</form>
```

Comment: Once you use correct tabbing you'll spot the mistake straight away...

Answer (score 0):

There are several obvious syntax errors you would not get if you learned to properly indent code. Every time you open a curly bracket `{`, tab everything inside it over to make it clear where blocks begin and end.

Having done so, I find your code looks like this:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function validate()
 {
    if(document.updateForm.fName.value == "")
    {
        alert(" Please provide your first name." );
        document.updateForm.fName.focus();
        return false;
    }
    {
        if(document.updateForm.lName.value == "")
        {
            alert(" Please provide your last name." );
            document.updateForm.lName.focus();
            return false;
 }
 </script>
```

You've obviously got some missing closings `}`, and some stray openings `{`.  The stray opening may be due to forgetting to type `else`.